# Get 403 while opening wss with node js to WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, whatsapp, http-status-code-403

I try to write an WhatsApp node, and want to open an wss connection, but always get an 403. Maybe someone see my error:

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://w8.web.whatsapp.com/ws', '["admin", "init", [0, 2, 7314], ["Mac OS 10.13.2", "Chrome"], true]');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('["admin", "init", [0, 2, 7314], ["Mac OS 10.13.2", "Chrome"], true]');
});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

this is only an test, and I hardcoded the values.

But the server always response an 403

Answer (score 1):

you have to put a header

```js
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
 
var client = new WebSocketClient();
 
client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});
 client.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e)
        }
client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');


    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });

    

});
 
client.connect('wss://w6.web.whatsapp.com/ws', null, null, {
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "ar,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", 
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Connection": "Upgrade",
"Host": "w6.web.whatsapp.com",
"Origin": "https://web.whatsapp.com" ,
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"Sec-WebSocket-Extensions": "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits",
'Sec-WebSocket-Key' : 'her ur key from header in url',
'Sec-WebSocket-Version':"13",
"Upgrade": "websocket",
"User-Agent": "here your agent"
}, null);
```